# Threading a GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, wxpython

Im writing a music downloader and the download takes awhile and the GUI freezes while this happens so how can i make it so that the GUI keeps running while the download is going

Here is the relevant code:

```
class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        self.retreive_range = 10
        self.convert_range = 10
        self.download_range = 100

        self.timer1 = wx.Timer(self, 1)
        self.timer2 = wx.Timer(self, 1)
        self.timer3 = wx.Timer(self, 1)

        self.count = 0
        self.count2 = 0
        self.count3 = 0

        self.getfile = Get_file()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer1, self.timer1)

        #All the GUI code!


    def retrieve(self, e):
        self.timer1.Start(100)
        self.text.SetLabel('Retrieving URL...')
        query = self.tc.GetValue()
        self.vidurl = self.getfile.get_url(query)



    def convert(self):
        self.timer2.Start(200)
        self.text.SetLabel('Converting...')
        self.res_html = self.getfile.get_file('http://www.youtube.com/%s'%self.vidurl)
        print self.res_html

    def download(self):
        self.text.SetLabel('Downloading...')
        threading.Thread(None, target=self.getfile.download_file(self.res_html))



    def OnTimer1(self, e):

        self.count = self.count + 1
        self.gauge.SetValue(self.count)

        if self.count == self.retreive_range:

            self.timer1.Stop()
            self.text.SetLabel('Url Retreived!')
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer2, self.timer2)
            self.convert()

    def OnTimer2(self, e):

        self.count2 = self.count2 + 1
        self.gauge.SetValue(self.count2)

        print self.count2

        if self.count2 == self.convert_range:

            self.timer2.Stop()
            self.text.SetLabel('Converted!')
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer3, self.timer3)
            self.download()

    def OnTimer3(self, e):

        self.count3 = self.count3 + 0.5
        self.gauge.SetValue(self.count3)

        if self.count3 == self.download_range:

            self.timer3.Stop()
            self.text.SetLabel('Downloaded!')
            self.gauge.SetValue(0)
```

i try to create a new thread but it doesn't help. can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code there are two errors:

```
def download(self):
    self.text.SetLabel('Downloading...')
    threading.Thread(None, target=self.getfile.download_file(self.res_html))
```

1. You must call the `start()` method of the `Thread` in order for it to execute the `target`
2. The `target` should be a *callable*, but doing:

   ```
   target=self.getfile.download_file(self.res_html)
   ```

   You are already calling the function *before the `Thread` is created*, and then the *return value* is assigned to `target`. This is wy you see the GUI freeze. You have to use a `lambda`:

   ```
   target=lambda: self.getfile.download_file(self.res_html)
   ```

   Or `functools.partial`:

   ```
   target=partial(self.getfile.download_file, self.res_html)
   ```

   In this way the function will be called in a different thread.

---

A style note: you do *not* have to specify the `None` when creating the `Thread`:

```
worker = threading.Thread(target=lambda: self.getfile.download_file(self.res_html))
worker.start()
```